# Python. Как сделать так чтобы y1 и y2 увеличивались в цикле? Пробовал cделать переменные global, не помогло

Tags: python, list

```
l = []

for i in range(10):
    l.append(  (x1, y1, x2, y2)  )  

while True:

    ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[0])

    wait(40)
    y1 += 1
    y2 += 1
    ev3.screen.clear()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они и увеличиваются. Но они увеличиваются в цикле `while True`. Т.е. сначала у вас 10 раз отрабатывает `l.append(  (x1, y1, x2, y2)  )` в цикле `for i in range(10)`, затем он завершается. Потом начинается цикл `while True`, где они бесконечно увеличиваются. У вас два несвязаных цикла.

Рекомендую:

1. Вообще убрать или `while True` или `for i in range(10)` (пример ниже);
2. Внимательно по учебнику изучить назначение циклов  и их синтаксис.
3. `global` стараться никогда не использовать, или в крайних случаях. Тут их применение вообще не имело никакого смысла, у вас же один кусок кода.

```
l = []

while True:

    l.append(  (x1, y1, x2, y2)  )  

    ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[0])

    wait(40)
    y1 += 1
    y2 += 1
    ev3.screen.clear()
```

Comment: Не работает. А так линия увеличивается и идет вниз ev3.screen.draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2). Но мне надо таких линий много, где x1, x2 у каждой линии разные, поэтому я хотел использовать список

Comment: вы спрашивали, как увеличивать в цикле y1 и у2. "Не работает" = "они не увеличиваются"? Я же понятия не имею, что это за `ev3.screen.`

Comment: Кстати, а с чего у вас "x1, x2 у каждой линии разные" будет, если вы "x1, x2" вообще не изменяете никак в коде, да и просите только об "y1 и у2"?

Comment: Одну игру пытаюсь сделать (в аппсторе Radical называется). ev3.screen.draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2) это значит вывести на экран линию с такими координатами. Линия должна двигаться вниз, и таких линий будет n количество. В начале я сделал так ev3.screen.draw_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    ev3.screen.draw_line(x1, y1-40, x2, y2-40) и так далее. -40 потом -80 и т.д., чтобы линии появлялись одна за другой на расстоянии 40. x1 x2 тоже меняются, но этот момент я опустил. Шас я почти все автоматизировал с помошью списка, все кроме увеличения y1  y2 чтоб линия двигалась. ev3.screen.clear() это очистить экран.

Comment: Типа ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[0]) ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[1]) ev3.screen.draw_line(*l[2]) так удобнее.

Comment: Объяснения непонятны. Сформулируйте нормально вопрос. Вы cпросили "Как сделать так чтобы y1 и y2 увеличивались в цикле? " Выше в точности дан ответ - они увеличиваются в цикле.

Comment: ok Получилось. Благодарю!